# Music Bot discord.js issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Ive been trying to get this code for a music bot to work, i have all the dependencies but i think its because the video i watched is from around 8 months ago and alot of the code is defunct.

Currently i get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined.
If someone can help me fix the problem and get it to work that would be amazing.

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(" ");


    switch(args[0]){
        case 'play':

                function play(connection, message){
                    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                    server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                    server.queue.shift();

                    server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                        if(server.queue[0]){
                            play(connection, message);
                        }else {
                            connection.disconnect();
                        }
                    })
                }

                if(!args[1]){
                    message.channel.send("you need to provide a link!");
                    return;
                }

                if(!message.member.voice.channel.join){
                    message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to play music!");
                    return;
                }

                if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                    queue: []
                }

                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.queue.push(args[1]);

                if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){

                    play(connection, message);

                })

            break;

    }
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message.member.voiceChannel.join()` might need to be changed to `message.member.voice.channel.join()` as of Discord v12

Comment: @ExodusBackup Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is coming from here :

```
if(!message.member.voice.channel.join){ message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to play music!"); return; }
```

You'll need to remove the .join part, because no such thing exists in Discord.js

Comment: Not to be rude, but im pretty sure ti does, as when typed join it comes up as a voice method in vscode. Also, its not that join thats causing the problem, its the one at the bottom of the the code

Comment: @ExodusBackup sorry, my bad. I've submitted another answer which should be right this time